# Node.js API & webpages with NGINX and AWS best practices

Tags: node.js, api, amazon-web-services, nginx, html

For a project i have to create website showing data from a database with data that changes frequently (sensor data: temperaturen, humidity,...). This by making an API to get the data. I created a REST api in Node.js to do this.

So Database -> API -> WEBSITE

What would be the best way to create the Dynamic website and what is the best practice to get the API to the outside using AWS? And in this solution, is it usefull to use NGINX in any way?

Other suggestions and literature about the subject are also welcome.

Answer (score 0):

To create the dynamic site i would say use angular JS/Angular2 which provides you the capability of two way data binding and make life easy to implement the website in quick period of time. For REST API you have used NODEJS which you can host to AWS and provide a reverse proxy viz; NGINX. the use of reverse proxy is useful in case of high traffic sites;which also protects the NodeJS server from direct exposure to Internet traffic and allows you a great deal of flexibility in using multiple application servers, in load balancing across the servers, and in caching content. So if you think your app is having heavy traffic you can use NGINX
So technology stack for you can be something like MEAN (MongoDB -if you also need to choose db; ExpressJs,NODEJS and ANGULAR) which hosted on AWS EC2 server.

Apart from this in case you dont want to maintain server you can also think of serverless architecture on aws (with lamda). Hope my answer will give you good pointers further.